# How to use AG-Grids agDateInput inside editing cell

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is it possible to use AG-Grids agDateInput Component inside an editing cell like below?

No matter how i try, it either renders nothing or it renders the Datepicker but does not save it's selected value.

```js
const exampleDates = ["2020/01/01", "2020/10/11"]
const colDef = {
   field: "receiptDate", 
   headerName: "Receipt Date", 
   cellEditor: "agDateInput",
   editable: true
 }
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: exampleDates,
    defaultColDef: {
        editable: true,
        sortable: true,
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 100,
        filter: true,
        resizable: true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`agDateInput` is not a cell editor, it is:

> Default date input used by filters.

See [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/components/#grid-provided-components). You're only supposed to use `agDateInput` for filters.

If you want a date cell editor, you're gonna have to create your own custom cell editor. There's a good example in the documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/components/#grid-provided-components) where they use a jQuery date picker.

Comment: agDateCellEditor is what you need.